# AWS codepipline rebuild only the affected monorepo apps

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have a NX Monorepo with 2 react applications and a shared library between them:

-apps
-app1
-app2
-libs
-global files for both apps

I have them both deployed on AWS codepipeline with s3 bucket and they share one monorepo repository, but the main issue here is that whenever I push some changes to the repo, no matter if they are in the libs(shared) or the app itself, the pipeline rebuilds all of the applications I have, my expected results are if I change something in the libs for example to rebuild all projects, because it affects them, but if I do a change in app1, which doesn't affect app2, AWS to rebuild only app1.
I read a lot of posts and landed on Lambdas and Lerna js, but everything looks pretty complicated since I am new to AWS
[image]

this is an image I landed on, it shows that I need to use lamba functions to check which part of the repo is changed and determine which pipline to rebuild, I would be really glad if someone simpliefies things for me so I can find easier solution or if someone dealt with this problem to help me find a solution.

Comment: were you able to figure it out? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you use codepipeline/codebuild with a self-created  build server container image including nx you don't need that logic. In that scenario nx inside build server watches for changes and builds only needed changes. Obviously you have to use EFS etc. for persistence.

Comment: I have one repo for 2 pipelines which include the 2 apps I have, when I change something in the repo whatever it is and push it, aws detects my changes on the repo and starts rebuilding both projects because they are using the same repo

Comment: Would using two pipelines be unnecessary in the scenario I presented? One monorepo -> one pipeline.

Comment: I am new to aws but, could one pipeline hold 2 different projects with 2 different urls ?

Comment: As far as I know. But you might need to add a script to buildspec file which determines which projects to build. That script might include "nx affected:apps" command etc. to determine changes and start a proper build.

Comment: Perhaps another alternative could be changing the nx cache default directory from /node_modules/.cache/nx to project home and not include it in the .gitignore file?
https://nx.dev/l/r/core-extended/computation-caching#customizing-the-cache-location